# How to display HTML if there are errors

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to display HTML if there are any errors.

```
{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>' : '' }}
```

This code shows the "raw" html output and doesn't translate it into code.

Can someone please show me the way? It's for an error validation form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
{!! $errors->has('first_name') ? '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>' : '' !!}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the double bang but I used the HTML code as a second parameter to has -_-